# How to make Google Chrome open PDFs in the internal PDF viewer instead of downloading them automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

How to prevent Chrome from downloading PDF files automatically and instead of that, show them online with internal PDF viewer?

Comment: If you have no download managers installed, [PDF Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) works well for me.

Comment: I got IDM but it's desactivated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a property of the browser, but of the headers sent by the server. If the server sends `Content-Disposition: Attachment`, then downloading is the right thing to to. If the server sends `Content-Disposition: Inline`, then displaying is the right thing to to.

If the server sends none, it is the browser, that must decide. Most browser assume `inline`.

**Edit**

Just tried it out: Current Chrome (Version 38.0.2125.111 on Ubuntu 12.04) assumes `inline`, so it will display, not download a PDF, if the server does not explicitly request so.

Answer (score -3):

Open Google Chrome. Then type  chrome://plugins/ in the browser and disable the PDF Viewer plugin.

You can also check this google support link!

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?hl=en

Comment: Ecactly the opposite!

Comment: @EugenRieck To be fair, the title was very misleading.

Comment: Whoever posted this answer did so once, was downvoted, I commented on this being the exact opposite, then he deleted the old answer and created a new one with the same content ... so I think the downvote is OK

Comment: @EugenRieck I'd suggest you to read the full answer. I have mentioned it as `disable`. It was just a curiosity to get the reply posted!

Comment: Yes, he asked for "force" and you answered "disable", then pulled back and repeated the same answer. Not my favorite style, so I downvoted.