# How to view pdf and doc files in Google Chrome instead of downloading them?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to stop Google Chrome from downloading .doc and .pdf files ? Chrome automatically starts to download files when clicked on them, but some browsers like Yandex opens them so you can review the article before downloading it. I saw [this discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/834254/how-to-make-google-chrome-open-pdfs-in-the-internal-pdf-viewer-instead-of-downlo) but I'm asking it anyway. Maybe there is an extension for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the **[Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn)** extension by Google, which uses the Google Docs Viewer.

After you install the extension, you'll find a `View File in a New Tab` context menu option.

Here's how it works.

[image: How to use Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer]

Comment: consider a non-animated graphic, and a smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome version of the [PDF Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm) extension which was developed for Firefox.

It doesn't do docs though. That needs another extension.